# Kafka Connect JDBC source : null value for field that is required and has no default value

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to set up the Kafka Connect Jdbc source connector with postgresql, but am getting the following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Conversion error: null value for field that is required and has no default value
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.convertToJson(JsonConverter.java:556)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.convertToJson(JsonConverter.java:650)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.convertToJsonWithEnvelope(JsonConverter.java:537)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.fromConnectData(JsonConverter.java:290)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:198)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:168)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:190)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is the configuration:

```
{
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
  "incrementing.column.name": "id",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "query": "SELECT * FROM comments",
  "table.whitelist": "comments",
  "mode": "incrementing",
  "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
  "topic.prefix": "comments_topic",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
  "name": "JdbcSourceConnector",
  "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/my-db?user=postgres&password=password",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
}
```

Any idea what the issue might be?

I also get this error sometimes:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Found null value for non-optional schema
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.validateSchemaValue(AvroData.java:981)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.fromConnectData(AvroData.java:359)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.fromConnectData(AvroData.java:532)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.fromConnectData(AvroData.java:324)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.fromConnectData(AvroConverter.java:76)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:198)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:168)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:190)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: 1) if you want to select all columns, have you considered using Debezium? 2) What's the schema of the table? 3) are there nulls in your table?

Comment: 1) yes. the only reason i'm using jdbc is because i'm going through a tutorial that is using it. 2) int4, int4, text, idea_comment_type, int4, bool, timestampz, timestampz. 3) no.

Comment: I'm not sure if the jdbc connector knows how to use `idea_comment_type` (is that really the column type?)

Comment: It's a custom type. I've tried removing it from the SELECT, but still getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Try add below json entry and check

```
"value.converter.nullable": true
```